# Identify a matching algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, e-commerce, nlp

I am fairly new to NLP/ML/Pattern Matching or Recognition. I was wondering what is the best way to match different items based on title, description, etc. For eg:

If there are 3 items:

```
item 1: Title: Belkin bluetooth headset USB - ABD13432
item 1: Description: This is a bluetooth device with the following specs: 
75 W power, 3.5 mm jack, etc
item 1: Model NO: ABD13432
item 1: UPC Code: 000000022221
item 1: product image: <img1>

item 2: Title: Belkin headset: 
item 2: Description: This is a device that works on RF, and has 2.5 mm jack with 25 W power 
item 2: Model No: 13432
item 2: UPC Code: 000022022221
item 2: product image: <img1>

item 3: Title: Belkin headset wireless - ABD 13432
item 3: Description: World's best headphone
item 3: Model No: ABD-13432 
item 3: UPC Code: 000000022221
item 3: product image: <img1>
```

item 1 and item 3 are the same and item 2 is *different*. UPC Code is generally a great indicator if it is the same item but the issue is a seller can input any UPC Code he wants. But an image matching is not necessarily a good indicator since the seller can input any image he wants to.

Comment: This is a very specific question, since I have mentioned the 5 attributes I have identified. Now i know WHAT i need to include but I need to know HOW i need to get this implemented. They both are completely different questions.

Comment: If you would have read the book I suggested, you would perfectly know how that works. P.S. you haven't accepted my last answer either.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, Model No and UPC obviously contributes more weights than other features.

When items have different Model No or UPC, you could consider semantic similarity for short sentences as another feature for you learning algorithm.

you might want to have a look [this paper](http://ants.iis.sinica.edu.tw/3BkMJ9lTeWXTSrrvNoKNFDxRm3zFwRR/55/Sentence%20Similarity%20Based%20on%20Semantic%20Nets%20and%20corpus%20statistics.pdf). As your case is in product/e-commerce domain, you might want to build you own domain corpus other than use general wordnet.